# Docker compose won't wait for Postgres to start

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

I made a Dockerfile based on python3 image, here is the code:

```
 FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file, that starts a simple Django app:

```
version: '2'

services:

  web:
    build: .
    env_file: composeexample/.env
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db", "--", "python", "news/"]
  db:
   image: postgresql
   volumes:
     - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I'm trying to execute the ./wait-for-postgres.sh script from this page: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

And it have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

However, my Postgres image on docker has its own Dockerfile, this is the PostgreSQL Dockerfile:

```
#
# example Dockerfile for https://docs.docker.com/examples/postgresql_service/
#
FROM ubuntu

# Add the PostgreSQL PGP key to verify their Debian packages.
# It should be the same key as https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

# Add PostgreSQL's repository. It contains the most recent stable release
#     of PostgreSQL, ``9.3``.
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Install ``python-software-properties``, ``software-properties-common`` and PostgreSQL 9.3
#  There are some warnings (in red) that show up during the build. You can hide
#  them by prefixing each apt-get statement with DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

# Note: The official Debian and Ubuntu images automatically ``apt-get clean``
# after each ``apt-get``

# Run the rest of the commands as the ``postgres`` user created by the ``postgres-9.3`` package when it was ``apt-get installed``
USER postgres

# Create a PostgreSQL role named ``docker`` with ``docker`` as the password and
# then create a database `docker` owned by the ``docker`` role.
# Note: here we use ``&&\`` to run commands one after the other - the ``\``
#       allows the RUN command to span multiple lines.
RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" &&\
    createdb -O docker docker

# Adjust PostgreSQL configuration so that remote connections to the
# database are possible.
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

# And add ``listen_addresses`` to ``/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf``
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

When I run docker-compose up, the first time the DB starts normally when I stop the service (with Ctrl+C) and try it once again the web service says that the DB service is starting.

Then i try to run the script, in this line:

```
command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db", "--", "python", "news/"]
```

But postgres sleeps forever, saying:

```
Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
./wait-for-postgres.sh: line 10: psql: command not found
```

Can you help me solve the riddle?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container uses `python:3` image which does not have PostgreSQL client installed in it, which is why your docker run fails for `web`.

You can fix the problem by installing the client using `apt`:

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-9.4 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

**Edit**: update PostgreSQL version, python 3 image has version 9.4. You can always add right PPA and install required version.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didin't work, it prompts the following error: 

E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-9.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-client-9.3'
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-9.3     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: @GiovanniKleinCampigoto sorry for that, I have updated the postgres version in the dockerfile which is available to install from python 3 image.

Comment: Ok, this solved my problem altough, when i try to launch my application it says: web_1 | Password for user postgres: 
web_1 | psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
web_1 | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
db_1  | 2017-07-21 14:15:23.609 UTC [14] postgres@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer, that means that i'm using the new postgres intalled and need to authenticate to it? Sorry, i'm kind of a begginer to it... haha

Comment: I run postgres in another container, i'm using a .env file to authenticate to the database, when I install the client in the python container it fails to authenticate to the database...

Comment: @GiovanniKleinCampigoto you can give a similar environment file for `db` with credentials using env variables mentioned in "Environment Variables" section here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: My problem was due to use of command docker-compose down, instead of docker-compose stop, this was removing all data from postgres, and deleting the images, so, my solution was: docker-compose stop, docker-compose start db, docker-compose logs db, until db starts, then docker-compose up, and everything works just fine...